# $g(x) | f(x)$ show that $(f(x)) \subset (g(x))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I have been given a problem recently that has been puzzling me for some time. The problem states

If $g(x), f(x)$ are elements of a polynomial ring $F[x]$ and $g(x) | f(x)$ show that $(f(x)) \subset (g(x))$

I know that the division algorithm for polynomials states that "Given two nonzero polynomials 
$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $F[x]$, then there exists two polynomials $t(x)$ and $r(x)$ in 
$F[x]$ such that $f(x) = t(x)g(x) + r(x)$ where $r(x) = 0$ or $\deg r(x) < \deg g(x)$

Any help on this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: What is big F? also does g(x)|f(x) mean that f divides g?

Comment: I have edited the problem to what I believe is the only sensible way to interpret it, i.e. a statement about the ideals generated by $f(x)$ and $g(x)$).

Comment: F[x] is the polynomial ring and g(x)|f(x) means that g(x) divides f(x)

Answer (score 2):

$g(x) | f(x)$ means $f(x)= g(x)h(x)$ (for some $h(x)$). So $f(x)\in (g(x))$, by definition. hence $(f(x)) \subset (g(x))$